# Running PowerShell Scripts in Komodo Edit

Tags: powershell, komodo, komodoedit

I have a hard time trying to run PowerShell Scripts from the "*Run Command*" within Komodo Edit on Windows 7.

The command that I am using is:

```
powershell -File "%F"
```

When I run it, it does not return anything to the console, it just keeps running till I terminate it.

I have tested it, with the following simple script:

```
Write-Host "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/572313/powershell-exe-can-hang-if-stdin-is-redirected) where `powershell.exe` waits for a STDIN prompt to return in certain cases, causing it to hang when no input is provided.

#### Solutions

1. Use `-InputFormat None` to indicate STDIN will not be used:
   `powershell.exe -InputFormat None -File "%F"`
2. Forward null input from the outer command scope so that STDIN returns:
   `powershell.exe -File "%F" < NUL`

#### Similar Questions

- 2010-11-09 [Silently executing a PowerShell script from WiX Hangs PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4138324)
- 2010-11-21 [Running PowerShell from MSdeploy runcommand does not exit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4238192)
- 2011-07-26 [Exiting VMware vSphere PowerCLI command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6824528)