# Wix setup window stuck in Windows Server 2008

Tags: wix, wix3.11

I have created installer which run CustomAction to launch exe and starts installation, Once its finished installation it exit automatically, after that  installer stuck and show dialog box with this message **please wait while the setup program is installs [setup name]**. Dialog box remains with this message and never goes to dialog box which has finish command button.
This works fine in Windows Server 2012/2016

I open Task Manager there I can see around 4 msiexec is running 2 with 32bit process, If I end 32 bit msiexec process then installer change to with Finish command button dialog box

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution from below link, Please see the answer given by Ben Collins.

[Silently executing a PowerShell script from WiX Hangs PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138324/silently-executing-a-powershell-script-from-wix-hangs-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

> ***Concurrency Considered Harmful***: You should not run embedded installers from within an MSI setup by means of custom actions. For MSI files there are technical impossibilities that exist ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51274911/129130), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49310996/129130), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50161928/129130), [**4**](https://serverfault.com/a/274675/20599)) - in essence only one MSI installation sequence can run at a time (unless you kick them off from the user interface, which is not advisable since your setup then fails silent install). For EXE files it is a legendary source of difficult-to-debug problems.
>
> ***Burn***: A better approach is to use a **WiX Burn bundle** (**`setup.exe`**) to kick off installs in sequence - one after the other. [Here is a quick sample of such a burn bundle running one EXE setup and one MSI setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065074/sql-server-named-instance-with-visual-studio-2017-installer-project/52071758#52071758). Burn features its own logging mechanism.

---

***Stuck Custom Action***: Technically the custom action(s) running the executable(s) in question got stuck, I guess. How have you sequenced the custom actions? Are they in the user interface sequence? What are they installing? Setups? Zip extractions? Something home-grown?

***msiexec.exe***: The **`msiexec.exe`** processes will stay behind in the process list for some time even after installations have completed successfully (about 10 minutes I think). They will certainly stay there - indefinitely - if the setup hung. There can be numerous **`msiexec.exe`** processes in the task list - even when everything is working correctly - because of the MSI file featuring GUI run in user context and custom actions run in various contexts. Several users can also be logged on.

> ***Logging***: Do you have logging enabled so you can check what happened? Please [**try to log the installation**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm) to see what it
>   says in there (see previous link for how to enable logging for all MSI installations - Section: *"Globally for all setups on a machine"*). Here is how to log a single installation:
>
> ```
>  msiexec.exe /i "Setup.msi" /L*V "C:\Setup.log"
> ```

The above command line already implements logging, but here are more details on logging and interpreting the log file:

- [Event logging, etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983606/visual-studio-installer-fails-on-aspnetdiagnosticpack-msi/49987350#49987350)
- [Interpreting MSI log files, etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026782/website-is-not-getting-created-in-iis-limited-edition-of-installshield/49028367#49028367)

---

Comment: Hi Stein thank for quick response and your guidance. I have created setup.msi installer package which launch exe application using customeaction(Not User interface customaction), the exe application executes sql scripts file, once sql script execution finished application close automatically and installer start executing next CustomeAction which runs batch file and installer hangs there only but this does not happen in Windows Server 20012/2016. I have execute msi setup with logs that you have suggested.

Comment: To add more with above comment- The batch file CustomAction runs batch file which has PowerShell command to run PowerShell script file.